# How to make rect move without skipping an X value when space is held down

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to have it so my rect moves in a straight line without skipping an X value.
It is moving when the space key is pressed.... but when I hold it down it just skips X values (it is jumping to without showing up)
Here's what I want... when the spacebar key is held down I want to have my red rect move without jumping and skipping frames.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPush)
var Xspeed = 5
var Xpos = 100

setInterval(draw, 1000)

function keyPush(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 32:
      Xpos = Xpos + 5
      break;
  }
}

function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
  ctx.fillStyle = "red"
  ctx.fillRect(Xpos, 0, 50, 50)
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: please post a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues:

- your setInterval is too high at 1000, that is one second in that time the player could have pressed the space bar a few times causing the effect you describe *(skips X values)*
- you are not clearing the canvas so when it draws the previous square is not deleted so it looks like the rectangle is growing instead of moving
- inside the draw we should not be getting the canvas and context that can be global variable
- the variable Xspeed was declared but not used, that would be perfect to use on the key events

Here is a working example:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown)
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp)

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
ctx.fillStyle = "red"

var Xspeed = 0
var Xpos = 10

setInterval(draw, 50)

function keyUp(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode == 32) Xspeed = 0
}
function keyDown(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode == 32) Xspeed = 2
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 999, 999)
  Xpos = Xpos + Xspeed
  ctx.fillRect(Xpos, 0, 20, 20)
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

On the keyDown I set the speed and on keyUp I remove it.